# Selenium page loads as blank unless browser is manually opened with same profile

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, web-crawler

I am using selenium for a crawling project, but I struggle with a specific [webpage](https://www.alljobs.co.il/) (both chrome and firefox).

I found 2 workarounds that work to an extend but I want to know why this issue happens and how to avoid it.

1) Opening chrome manually and then opening selenium with my user profile.
If i manually start chrome and then run:

```
from selenium import webdriver
options.add_argument(r"user-data-dir=C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

the page loads as intended

2) Passing a variable in the request
by appending `/?anything` to the url the page loads as intended in selenium

For some reason the webpage has a function in the header despite not loading... I suspect this could be a clue but I do not know enough to determine the cause.

Comment: sort of points to a cookie... I don't think Selenium's browser session will have access to that profile's cookies if another browser already has it open.  Appending "/?anything" to the path may also change the path of the cookie.

Comment: If that's the case wouldn't workaround 1) be unnecessary? doesn't the user profile already contain the cookies?

Comment: I don't really understand what's happening, but the site does seem to want to delete a cookie on load.  That would fail (I think) if you already have the browser/profile open.  No idea why that would cause a blank page though.  It also seems to redirect to root... it sets the location to "/" which would be root.

Comment: I am a little confused by "if you already have the browser/profile open.", It works if i have chrome with my profile already open but only if I open it manually, I need to execute chrome.exe first

Comment: that's workaround "1)", no?

Comment: Thanks for trying to assist on the matter, I am too confused by this weirdness myself I have managed to use nodejs with puppeteer-extra to load the website correctly, I would still love knowing what's the issue but it's not any priority.

Comment: "that's workaround "1)", no?" yes

Comment: The only difference there would involve certain user data that will be locked.  (I don't think you can share the data with a Selenium session using the same profile...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone finds things, I figure that out and it's related to the website's bot detection safety measures.
I eventually got around to using puppeteer with puppeteer extra stealth and imitation of human behavior.